# Spotify Simple Player Runs on iPhone simulator, but not actual iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, spotify

Basically, the Simple Player Spotify sample app runs perfectly on the iPhone 6.0 simulator, but it will not run on my iPhone when I tried to test it on there. This also happens when I try to test the app I built out of the "empty cocoalibspotify project". It runs perfectly on the simulator, but gives a ton of error messages when it tries to build on my iPhone.

Am I just missing a step before I build on the actual phone?

for examples of the errors, please see the following link
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgvZj.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The Spotify library you are trying to use here does not have armv7s code which is the default architecture of your iPhone 5. You need to remove the armv7s architecture from your build settings so that it compiles with armv7 instead.

It is a problem that all vendors of static libraries are having since Apple released armv7s devices (iPhone 5, iPad 4) because you cannot have a statib lib that supports i386+armv6+armv7+armv7s.